# Provide two data providers at a same time in a data grid in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

Can we provide 2 data providers at a same time in a data grid in flex 4. If yes, how ? Please explain with example.

```
<s:DataGrid id="dgDest" dataProvider="{destProds && ??}" width="100%" height="100%" editable="true" 
                         selectionMode="multipleRows"
                         gridItemEditorSessionStarting="dgDest_gridItemEditorSessionStartingHandler(event)"
                         paste="dgDest_pasteHandler(event)"
                         >
                <s:columns>
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <!--<s:GridColumn width="20" dataField="MNF_DESC" sortCompareFunction="{sortNumeric('MNF_DESC')}"  headerText="Manufacturer"
                                      headerRenderer="{new ClassFactory(styleManager.getStyleDeclaration('.generic').getStyle('spreadHeaderRenderer'))}"/>-->
                        <s:GridColumn width="20" dataField="MNF_DESC" sortCompareFunction="{sortNumeric('MNF_DESC')}"  headerText="Manufacturer"
                                      headerRenderer="{ new ClassFactory(styleManager.getStyleDeclaration('.generic').getStyle('spreadHeaderRenderer'))}" />         
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="PRODUCT_DESC" headerText="Products" editable="true"
                                      headerRenderer="{ new ClassFactory(styleManager.getStyleDeclaration('.generic').getStyle('spreadHeaderRenderer'))}"/>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="PACK_DESC" headerText="Packs" editable="false"
                                      headerRenderer="{ new ClassFactory(styleManager.getStyleDeclaration('.generic').getStyle('spreadHeaderRenderer'))}"/>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="NDF_CODE" headerText="NDF No." width="80" editable="false"
                                      headerRenderer="{ new ClassFactory(styleManager.getStyleDeclaration('.generic').getStyle('spreadHeaderRenderer'))}"/>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:columns>
            </s:DataGrid>
```

I tried like this but this is not working. please explain how this could be possible.

Answer (score 1):

A Spark `DataGrid` cannot take 2 `dataProviders`.

If you need to merge the data, do it before you pass it to the `DataGrid`, on the server code or in the client code.

Comment: thanx for the answer.

Comment: Sure. Vote up and accepting my answer will be appreciated.

Comment: mean to say we can  not pass as second dataprovider={""}??

Comment: Sorry - Not sure what you mean. Could you please explain ?